# Mathjax not working

Tags: discussion, mathjax

When viewing equations on this site, I see only LaTeX markup.  Why are equations not rendering?  Javascript is enabled on my browser, so MathJax should be working?

Using Chrome on Mac.

Comment: What happened to my comments which were done (still) on MSE?

Comment: @Edward Do [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297) to create a bookmark that renders the code when you click it.

Comment: @Git Gud Thanks!  However, the bookmarks don't work for me.  I tried the various solutions robjohn gives.  Even clicking his javascript-launching links on [this page](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) doesn't render the bit of test-markup appearing on the page, so this would not seem to be the problem...

Comment: Maybe rebooting your computer helps...

Comment: It works now... I didn't even reboot since the last try, nor even closed the browser nor navigated away from the page (although none of these things had effect earlier).

Comment: Feel like deleting this question?  "Mathjax doesn't work" "Oh wait, now it does" is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: In the last couple of days this has hit me too in all browsers I've tested: Safari, Chrome, Firefox. There is a connection timeout when loading things from cdn.mathjax.org. After a long time, the page is rendered without rendering the formulas. The Javascript console in Chrome shows "Failed to load resource". Safari says "Failed to load resource: The request timed out.".

Comment: @Douglas Maybe, but not yet.

Comment: I am having the same problem. When I open the Javascript console, it says" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML
Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined cdn.sstatic.net/js/mathjax-editing.js?v=6da1b6cfe19f:3"

Comment: I'm having this same error. What on earth happened?

Comment: \multicolumn does not work in the MathJax of stackexchange.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/no-latex-rendering-at-all

Comment: As of mid-2017, cdn.mathjax.org has been replaced. The new URL is https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full

Comment: $2x + 3 = 14234 $ test

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome, open the menu (usually on the right hand side next to the URL field) and select "tools" and open up the "Javascript console".

In the same window, then load the Math.SE home page.  You should see something like this

[image]

Please edit your original question above to include either a screen grab of the error messages you see, or copy and paste the messages from the javascript console as text/code into your original question.

Since MathJax is working for most of us, this is likely a configuration issue on your end. We need more information before we can troubleshoot the error.

Comment: Thanks Willie.  It seems to be working again.  I'll post such errors though if this is a persistent problem.

Comment: In the last couple of days this has hit me too in all browsers I've tested: Safari, Chrome, Firefox. There is a connection timeout when loading things from cdn.mathjax.org. After a long time, the page is rendered without rendering the formulas. The Javascript console in Chrome shows "Failed to load resource". Safari says "Failed to load resource: The request timed out.".

Comment: @lhf: unfortunately, if there's a connection time-out error, there's nothing you or StackExchange can do to fix it, except maybe possibly switching to a different DNS server if you suspect the problem to be caused by DNS resolution.

Comment: It is not a DNS problem. Other sites were ok, even `www.mathjax.org`. After a few hours it went back to normal. Let's hope it stays that way.

Comment: I'm getting a `Blocked loading mixed active content "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"` error in Firefox while using HTTPS Everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

MathJax fails to load if the site is being viewed through HTTPS, which it is if HTTPS Everywhere. Disable HTTPS Everywhere for just this site, and then reload the page without HTTPS.

Comment: The problem is there is mixed content on the page. The MathJax content appears to be delivered via HTTP. The rest of the page is delivered via HTTPS. (I didn't check this in detail. I observed that the only part of the page that didn't work in HTTPS was the MathJax content.) Disabling HTTPS Everywhere and using the HTTP page is one way to correct this problem. The other is to accept the mixed content.

Comment: @WayneJohnston The MathJax JS library is indeed loaded over HTTP, via the script tag `<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>`, which you can see in the source of pages using MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

The math symbols stopped working for me 4 days ago on Windows7/Firefox 47.0.1 (showing dollars everywhere). I observed it for 4 days.

I cleaned up my FF session few times. That didn't help. I tried `http` versus `https`. That didn't help. I was able to reach mathjax website, I was able to load the mathjax javascript in the browser and read the javascript code. The samples on the mathjax website were showing correctly rendered.

I changed my `User Agent` (using ***`User Agent Switcher 0.7.3.1`***) to `iPhone`, loaded the site, the site suddenly started to work. I changed the User Agent back to Default, hoping that I could reproduce the problem. But, within 3 minutes, the problem had gone away without a trace. Changing UA seem to have flushed out some configuration setting in my FF OR forced me to reach a different mirror site of mathjax. I am not sure.

Comment: how to change the user agent can you please tell me